# Drupal 8 getting a referenced entity's field value in its parent in twig

Tags: drupal-theming, drupal-8

This is my setup. I have a **custom block type** that has a **reference entity** field. It references a **content type** of "Products". The Products content type has a reference entity field to a **taxonomy vocabulary** of "Series".

The Series taxonomy contains a field that I need to get the value of in my custom block's product field theme. I basically have a block of 5 products, each product belonging to a series. In my theme, I need to apply a series field value to each product.

Is there a way to get to this value strictly from twig? I have tried countless combination chains to try to get to it.

I have my block--bundle--product_series_block.html.twig file that surrounds the products.

```
<div {{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}
     data-ng-controller="ProductsController as vm">
  <div class="container">
    {{ title_prefix }}
    {% if label %}
      <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
    {{ title_suffix }}
    <div class="product-holder">
      {% block content %}
        {{ content }}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then that goes to my field--field-products.html.twig where I want to get the series for use in a data-series html attribute.

```
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field__items') }} data-series="{{ cant_figure_this_out }}">
  {% for item in items %}
    <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1/ You can get it at node template level with something like this:**

```
node.field_serie.0.get('entity').getTarget().getValue().getName()
```

If you want it as an array ...:

```
{% set series = [] %}
{% for key, item in node.field_serie %}
  {% set series = series|merge( [item.get('entity').getTarget().getValue().getName()] )  %}
{% endfor %}
```

**2/ You can also get it at field template level:**

```
{% set series = [] %}
{% for key, item in item['content']['#node'].field_serie %}
  {% set series = series|merge( [item.get('entity').getTarget().getValue().getName()] )  %}
{% endfor %}
```

**3/ Then you can use something like (this probably needs more work):**

```
attributes.setAttribute('data-series', series|join(',')|escape
```

Comment: Thank you! The 2nd method helped for what I needed.